# Are the order statistics minimal sufficient for a location-scale family?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics

Suppose we have a location-scale family with pdf $$\frac{1}{\sigma}f(\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}).$$ Let $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$,..., $X_n$ be a random sample from the location-scale family. Is the statistics $$T(X) = (X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}, X_{(3)},..., X_{(n)})$$ minimal sufficient for the parameters ($\mu$,$\sigma$)? ($X_{(k)}$ is the kth order statistic) I have read somewhere that $T(X)$ is minimal sufficient for the parameters ($\mu$,$\sigma$) (I know that it is sufficient).

Can someone please help? If the answer is positive, can someone please give me a proof?

Answer (score 6):

This question is Example 6.10, page 36, in [Lehmann and Casella Theory of Point Estimation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387985026). If the density $f$ is unknown or simply outside exponential families, like the Cauchy distribution, the order statistics $$T(X) = (X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}, X_{(3)},..., X_{(n)})$$ is minimal sufficient.

The result is based on Theorem 6.12, page 37, that, for a finite family of distributions $\mathcal{P}=\{p_0,\ldots,p_k\}$, and a sample $X$, the statistic $$T(X) = (p_1(X)/p_0(X),\ldots,p_k(X)/p_0(X))$$ is minimal sufficient. The result follows from this property by considering $n$ different values of the Cauchy parameters and by noticing that if $T$ is minimal sufficient for $\mathcal{P}_0$ and sufficient for $\mathcal{P}_1\supset\mathcal{P}_0$, then it is minimal sufficient for $\mathcal{P}_1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What exactly is a finite family? What are the $p_i$ ?

Comment: Sorry for asking, but what is a 'finite family of distributions'? I have heard of things like the exponential family and the location-scale family, but not a 'finite family'.

Comment: Ps: You can access the relevant pages in Lehmann-Casella on [amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387985026).

Comment: @Xi'an I believe theorem 6.12 only suits a finite family of distributions. However, the Cauchy distribution family is infinite, how to use 6.12 to prove Cauchy?

Comment: @Tan: This is in my last sentence, namely that minimal sufficiency for a smaller collection of distributions implies minimal sufficiency for a larger (and possibly infinite) one.

Comment: @Xi'an Wow! That is mind-blowing! But is it true? If $P_0$ is a subset of $P_1$, we can find a map from $P_1$ to $P_0$. If $T$ is minimal sufficient for $P_0$, it means that the range of $T$ and the likelihood shape of the elements of $P_0$ is a one-to-one mapping. If $T$ is sufficient for $P_1$, it means that whenever values of $T$ same, the likelihood shapes of two elements of $P_1$ are the same. However, I don't think it proves that whenever values of $T$ different, the shape of the likelihood function of elements in $P_1$ different. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I got it. The lemma 6.14. Thanks!